# How to count occurrences of a foreign table id in a certain table in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

So I have the following table:

```
Table A
a_id    b_id

Table B
b_id    b_name
```

I want to count how many times the `id` in table B is shown or used as a value in the `b_id` column in Table A. Presumably, the result should be something as such:

```
ID     count     name
1      10        aaaa
2      8         bbbb
3      11        cccc
```

I considered using the query below:

```
Select b_id from table_b
```

to get all the ids. Then iterate over each one of them and count them like this :

```
Select count(*) from table_a where b_id = ''
```

But the process is just too long. I want to make it a little shorter in within one query. But I don't know how to iterate over each rows using SQLite language.

(Even just a push to the right direction will help. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT b_id AS ID,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM TableA
        WHERE TableA.b_id = TableB.b_id
       ) AS count,
       b_name AS name
FROM TableB;
```

Comment: Is this more efficient? I can add a LIMIT before the FROM keyword right?

Comment: Like for example I only need 10 results

Comment: It's likely to be more efficient than a join. And how to use LIMIT would be a different question; use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: I can't see how this is more efficient than join.  What is your evidence?  At the best it is the same.  At the worst it will execute a sub-query for every id.  Have you tried this with (for example) a 1000 entries in a table?

Comment: @Gray SQLite executes the COUNT in the same way (if there is a proper index). The difference is in the additional processing needed by the GROUP BY (see the [EXPLAIN](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) output).

Comment: Interesting CL.  Thanks for the details.  Maybe add those to the answer?

Answer (score 2):

The following sql query should work :

```
   SELECT      a.a_id, 
               COUNT(b.b_id)    
   FROM        Table_A a
   JOIN  Table_B b on a.b_id=b.b_id
   GROUP BY    a.a_id
```

The above is working :

[image]

Is it your requirement?